# Tensorflow CIFAR10 distributed training, accuracy

Tags: tensorflow

I am seeing very low accuracy running CIFAR10 distributed training. I see a loss of 2.39 even after 1M steps running on 2 P2.8X(8 Tesla K80 GPUs on each machine). I have one ps on each machine and 1 worker for every GPU (total of 16 workers) and running with a batch_size of 8.

After successful training , **the accuracy on the validataion dataset using the [cifar10_eval](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py) is 0.010**

I am running the distributed version of cifar10 training using the model in [tensorflow tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10). I used code sample from [distributed tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed#replicated_training) to run it distributed mode. The distributed version of the code is below. **what is wrong in this code and how can i fix it to get better accuracy?**

**command used to run ps and workers** similar to

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='0' python cifar10_multi_machine_train.py --batch_size 8
--data_dir=./cifar10_data --train_dir=./train_logs --ps_hosts=host1:2222,host2:2222
--worker_hosts=host1:2230,host1:2231,host1:2232,host1:2233,host1:2234,host1:2235,
host1:2236,host1:2237,host2:2230,host2:2231,host2:2232,host2:2233,
host2:2234,host2:2235,host2:2236,host2:2237
--job_name=worker --task_index=0
```

**distributed training code**

```
if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

    # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):

        global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

        # Get images and labels for CIFAR-10.
        images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()

        # Build inference Graph.
        logits = cifar10.inference(images)

        # Build the portion of the Graph calculating the losses. Note that we will
        # assemble the total_loss using a custom function below.
        loss = cifar10.loss(logits, labels)

        train_op = cifar10.train(loss,global_step)

    # The StopAtStepHook handles stopping after running given steps.
    hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(num_steps=FLAGS.num_steps), _LoggerHook()]

    # The MonitoredTrainingSession takes care of session initialization,
    # restoring from a checkpoint, saving to a checkpoint, and closing when done
    # or an error occurs.
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                            is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                            checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.train_dir,
                                            save_checkpoint_secs=60,
                                            hooks=hooks) as mon_sess:
        while not mon_sess.should_stop():
            # Run a training step asynchronously.
            # See `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` for additional details on how to
            # perform *synchronous* training.
            # mon_sess.run handles AbortedError in case of preempted PS.
            mon_sess.run(train_op)
```